# Update existing entity with inline options doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Consider this code:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void AssertAutoMapper()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Entity, EntityModel>()
                    .ReverseMap();

                cfg.CreateMap<Message, MessageModel>()
                    .ReverseMap();
            }
        );

        Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var model = new EntityModel() { Messages = new List<MessageModel>() {  } };
        var entity = new Entity() { Messages = new List<Message>() { new Message() { Content = "Test" } } };
        Mapper.Map(model, entity, opt => opt. ConfigureMap().ForMember(x => x.Messages, o => o.UseDestinationValue()));

        Assert.IsTrue(entity.Messages.Count == 1);
    }
```

My first assert is Ok, but the second fails.
I tried with `Ignore()` but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not working in the way you did, but configuring during initialization works.

```
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Entity, EntityModel>()
                        .ReverseMap().ForMember(x => x.Messages, o => o.Ignore());
                    cfg.CreateMap<Message, MessageModel>()
                        .ReverseMap();
                });

        Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var model = new EntityModel() { Messages = new List<MessageModel>() { } };
        var entity = new Entity() { Messages = new List<Message>() { new Message() { Content = "Test" } } };
        Mapper.Map(model, entity);
        Assert.IsTrue(entity.Messages.Count == 1);
```

**EDIT**:

Inline configuration has no effect if you have provided configuration already in `Initialize` method. So to get it working you must do:

```
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { });
        Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        var model = new EntityModel() { Messages = new List<MessageModel>() { } };
        var entity = new Entity() { Messages = new List<Message>() { new Message() { Content = "Test" } } };
        Mapper.Map(model, entity, opt => opt.ConfigureMap().ForMember(x => x.Messages, o => o.Ignore()));
```

Comment: Yes i expect in my can it's override my main settings, in your case my assertIsValid Fail

Comment: @Arnaud,  inline configuration is not meant to be for overriding. Read more here: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Inline-Mapping.html#inline-configuration. And assert doesn't fail in neither case.